# In JS can you inherit methods from your class and properties from an instance of your parent class?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

In building an order tracking software, I want an inheritance structure that looks something like this

```
      Default SKU Propreties
              |
        ----------...
        |
    SKU 001
        |
   --------...
   |
Item AAA
```

I want the Item objects to inherit properties and methods from their parent SKU objects, but also have methods specific to Item objects.

I have tried something like `Class Item extends SKU`, but of course this just makes the SKU class the Item instance's ancestor, and not the SKU instance which has the relevant properties. I know you can do something like `itemInstance = Object.create(skuInstance)` to inherit from a SKU instance object, but then itemInstance does not get any methods defined on the Item class.

Thank you for your help :)

**Edit, additional info:**

I want a SKU instance to have some properties and methods like:

```
SKU 001
Name: 'Custom T-Shirt'
getLaborCost()
```

I want each Item instance to inherit the values that are common to all Items under that SKU. I want it also to have properties like `proofs` that can be unique to each Item instance.

Right now I am achieving this by having "item" object instances have SKU instances as their prototypes. The prototype ancestry looks like this:

```
SKU Class (with methods)
v
SKU instance (with properties)
v
"item" instance (with properties)
```

However, this means I can't have items be actual instances of an Item class and get unique methods like `attachProof()`, which I would not want to be available on the SKU instance object.

from my comment to MikeM:
"I want the user during program execution to be able to change the `skuInstance.name` and all of its items have their `itemInstance.name` resolve to the current value. I also want the user to be able to override some item instance properties which would otherwise be inherited."

Comment: If early definition it won't work but as a later-called function you won't have issues generally!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your use case.  Would it be possible to provide a code (or pseudocode) example that shows the scenario and the desired outcome?

Comment: An item doesn't have a "is a" relationship to `SKU`, so why should it have methods of SKU's? What you can do is create a class for each item kind that you want to have special methods for, and then make those classes be instances of a SKU metaclass.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I have edited the original post to hopefully clarify a bit.

@Bergi I have done some research now into metaclasses and I think I can envision some situation where your suggestion would work for my needs. Namely having a new Item class generated for each SKU which has its prototype being the SKU instance, and each of the items underneath having their prototype be the generated class. 

I wish I could picture a more "elegant" way of solving this, but I do think that would work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you may be able to meet your requirements without using inheritance.

Note that by *properties* I mean methods also, as methods are properties whose value is a function.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for some cautions related to the use of `Object.assign`.

```js
class Item {
  #sku;
  constructor(props) {
    const { sku, ...others } = props; 
    Object.assign(this, others);
    this.#sku = sku;
  }
  get name() { return this.#sku?.name }
  set name(val) { /* disallow */ }
  // Add further properties of all Item instances...
}

class SKU {
  #itemProps;
  constructor(props) { 
    const { itemProps, ...others } = props; 
    Object.assign(this, others);
    this.#itemProps = itemProps;
  }  
  item(props) {
    return new Item({ ...this.#itemProps, ...props, sku: this });
  }
  // Add further properties of all SKU instances...
}

let sku1 = new SKU({ name: 'Custom T-Shirt', itemProps: { color: 'red' } });
let item1 = sku1.item({ size: 'L' });

console.log(item1.name);      // "Custom T-Shirt"
sku1.name = 'Slogan T-Shirt';
console.log(item1.name);      // "Slogan T-Shirt"
console.log(item1.color);     // "red"
console.log(item1.size);      // "L"
```

Comment: Hey MikeM! Thank you very much for your answer.

I unfortunately don't think this will totally match my requirements. I want the user during program execution to be able to change the `skuInstance.name` and all of its items have their `itemInstance.name` resolve to the current value. I also want the user to be able to override some item instance properties which would otherwise be inherited. This is why I was envisioning inheritance.

Comment: It seems like you are adding to the requirements on the fly, or at least that you haven't detailed them properly in your question. The first of your requirements is simple to implement using the structure I suggest by passing a reference to the sku instance to the `new Item` call, and the second seems to be insisting on inheritance even though it is unsuitable here and the same effect can be better achieved via other means.

Comment: Hi MikeM. Yes, there are many requirements to this particular problem, and I omitted as much as I could in an effort to be concise. I apologize for leaving out necessary details. I would be curious to hear your ideas you mention in your last sentence. I don't quite understand how passing a `this` reference to the `new Item` call would achieve the effect without somehow 'faking' the inheritance.

Comment: Answer updated. Note that I am only trying to stimulate further ideas here by giving an example of how JavaScript's flexibility can circumvent the need to force code into the straight-jacket of inheritance. I threw in some private fields just for fun.

Comment: After contemplating all the answers and suggestions provided, I have successfully implemented a version of your suggestion. It seems as though while I was inspired by some aspects of OOP inheritance, I don't need to conform my system to it, as you suggested. Lesson learned, OOP inheritance has a specific purpose, which does not align with what I needed. Thank you :)